# Android Disable any onTouch

Tags: java, android, events

I have developed an Android App that communicates via HTTP-Request with a server.
Some times it takes more time for a request so the app shows just a black screen and passes some seconds later. Sometimes the black screen appears some seconds later and you can send the request again and again.

Is there any possibility to disable the onTouch-Events or show a layer while the screen is loading?

Thank you.

Comment: you are bocking the user UI. you need to perform the HTTP-Request in an AsynTask, and prompt the user for a waiting dialog for example.
Its better to let the user control the application.

Comment: Yep, what @Anis said. Please post your code, and we can suggest fixes for it. Also, the proper solution is not to disable onTouch events, but rather track whether your request is running using a semaphore, and now fire off a second request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an `asyncTask` and launch your httprequest in the `doInBackground()` method, and for blocking the user , just display a `ProgressDialog` :

```
class YourRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

        ProgressDialog progress;
        Context context;

        public YourRequestTask(Context context) {
             this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(context, null,"Please wait...");
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //do your work here for your http request
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            progress.dismiss();
                        Log.i(TAG, "result is "+result.toString());
        }

    }
```